# How to increase the height of WYSWYG Editor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, ckeditor

I have a [WYSWYG](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/) editor.

I want to extend it down a bit so I don't have to scroll down to see my contents. I'm trying to follow the documentation, but that doesn't seem to take effect.

[image]

HTML/Blade

```
{{-- Description --}}
<div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-sm-12">

        <textarea name="description" rows="100" cols="80" id="description">
            {{ base64_decode($portfolio->description) }}
        </textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );
        </script>

    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('#description').froalaEditor({
        height: 1000
  })
});


</script>
```

Comment: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_resize.html

Comment: Documentation says `height: 1000` should work. Either something else is overwriting that (CSS maybe?) or you are using a different version of "froalaEditor" thatn the one I could find documentation for.

Comment: It looks like you may be initializing ckeditor twice... once with `CKEDITOR.replace` in the html, and then once with `$('#description').froalaEditor`. Maybe one is superceding the other? I would comment out both scripts, then try `$('#description').froalaEditor({height: 1000})` in your dev console in the browser to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Please use [height setting](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-height) either for single editor instance configuration (directly in `replace`/`inline` methods):

```
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'description', {
      height: '200px'
  } );
</script>
```

or for all editor instances you will use inside your application (inside `ckeditor/config.js`):

```
CKFinder.customConfig = function( config ) {
   config.height = '200px';
   // other settings...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to solve my problem.

```
CKEDITOR.config.height = 1000;
```

---

Final code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

        <textarea name="description" rows="100" cols="80" id="description">
            {{ base64_decode($portfolio->description) }}
        </textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );
            CKEDITOR.config.height = 1000;
        </script>

    </div>
</div>
```